# Construction of a Partition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations

Can someome help me to proe the following result:

There exist two functions $\chi
$ and $\phi$ valued in the interval $[0, 1],$ belonging respectively to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0((0, \frac{1}{2}))$ and to $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0(\frac{1}{2},3),$ and such that
\begin{align*}
&\forall x\in [0,+\infty[,\quad\quad\chi^2(x) +\sum_{j\ge0}\phi^2(2^{-j}
x) = 1
\end{align*}

This is what i tried to do:

I started by considering  $\chi_0\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\left[0,1\right[)$ such that $\chi_0=1$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and $\chi_0=0$ when $x\ge\frac{3}{4}$ . And then i defined $\chi_1(x)=(1-\chi_0)(x)\chi_0(x/4)$.

But I don't know how to contitue. Please help me to construct such a partition. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{D}(\text{interval})$? Differentiable?

Comment: I mean $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_0((0, 4/3))$ that is smooth and supported in (0, 4/3)

Comment: I started by considering $\chi_0\in\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\left[0,1\right[)$ such that $\chi_0=1$ in $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and $\chi_0=0$ in when $x\ge\frac{3}{4}$  and then i defined $\chi_1(x)=(1-\chi_0)(x)\chi_0(x/4)$. But I don't know how to contitue. Please help me to construct such a partition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just two things: $q$ is probably $x$, and what do you mean by *radial* - since this is 1-dimensional? Oh and also, what you have tried should be included in the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: yes you are right i will edit my post

Comment: i edited my post